react-native fetch causes [TypeError: Network request failed]
When I visit http://example-api.com/automobile-list (not the real FQDN for confidentiality reasons) in my web browser, I see an array of json objects listing vehicles.  This is exactly what I expect.
I have the following react-native code:
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://example-api.com/automobile-list");
    console.log("Completed Fetch");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error: ' e);
  }

Running this line on a physical android device or android emulator always causes this line to print:
Error: [TypeError: Network request failed]

I can never get the Completed Fetch to appear.
In my android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, I have already added this line android:usesCleartextTraffic="true".
Then I ran these commands:
cd android
gradlew.bat clean
gradlew.bat --stop

cd ..
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npm cache clean --force
npm start -- --reset-cache

# then select android when option appears

This causes Error: [TypeError: Network request failed] to appear.
I also tried
cd android
gradlew.bat clean
gradlew.bat --stop
gradlew.bat assembleRelease

#copy the apk file to my phone and then install it.

Running the apk file causes Error: [TypeError: Network request failed] to appear.
How do I resolve this issue?
